# Install non-whitelisted psql extension on Heroku postgres?

Tags: postgresql, heroku, heroku-postgres

[This Heroku page](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-extensions-postgis-full-text-search) gives a list of whitelisted extensions for Heroku psql. Is it possible to install the (non-whitelisted) psql [`http`](https://github.com/pramsey/pgsql-http) extension on Heroku postgres?

---

A little more background on my problem:

I want to create a database trigger that makes an HTTP request to a server every time a table is updated in the database -- the `http` extension (link above) does just that. Is there another way to notify a web server any time a database is updated (using Heroku psql)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to install the (non-whitelisted) psql http extension on Heroku postgres?

The short answer, no. It's not possible to install extensions outside of what's on their custom whitelist. The longer answer is that it is generally an anti-pattern to hand off http workloads to your database unless you have a very, very good reason to do so. Many ORMs have lifecycle hooks that you can use to fire off requests depending on what happens in the database. Check out [ActiveRecord’s Callbacks](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html) for an example.